# Instantiating a tomcat WEB-INF\class\myclass from tomcat lib using classloader

Tags: tomcat, classloader, web-inf, contextclassloader

I am trying to load a class present in a war file in tomcat from a class in a jar in tomcat lib. I am doing this using Class.forname("myclass") but the application is throwing class not found exception. i guess this is because the webapp will have its own class loader. can someone suggest how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

This is by design - you can't do that. With the hierarchical classloaders that tomcat is using, you don't have a chance to load a class that's contained a webapp from a class loaded from the global classpath unless you build your own classloading mechanism - which I wouldn't recommend.

I'd rather like to know what problem you're trying to solve with this solution attempt. I can't think of any underlying problem where this would be the right solution for.

Comment: The solution is not the correct one but the scenario is like this. The common classes which is used by all the war files are placed in tomcat lib and I have a need to get some data inside a class in tomcat lib which is same as done in a class in war file. I do not want to copy paste the same code but instantiate the class inside the war file and get the data

Answer (score 0):

You should use Thread#getContextClassLoader() to instantiate classes that could be a part of your WAR distribution. But check that Tomcat initialises it with the web app classloader.

Comment: I tried using the webappclassloader for org.apache.catalina but getting a null pointer in .start() method

Comment: Don't try to initialise classloaders on your own. Use the one that is already initialised by Tomcat.